# Use std container iterator in template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, iterator

I can't use the std container iterator in a template class.

I get this errors :
**error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'iterator'**
**error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'**

Here the source code:

```
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template<typename TParam>
class MyClass
{
public:
    using TFunction = std::function<void(TParam)>;
    using TContainer = std::list<TFunction>;
    using TIterator = TContainer::iterator; // compilation error here!
};
```

How to use the iterator of the container in the templated class?

Comment: The compiler error is common, and what I wanted to do is specific, so I didn't find the same question..

Answer (score 1):

You need the **typename** keyword

```
using TIterator = typename TContainer::iterator;
```

Depending on what TContainer ends up being, the **iterator** could be a static member or a nested type. The compiler will assume it's not a type unless you explicitly specify that with the typename keyword. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more details.

Comment: Great it works ! Why this keyword here?

Comment: @AntoineLafarge: See my edit